# How to organize similar struct to avoid duplication without sacrificating memory

Tags: go

I have to refactor a code, and I don't know how to best define my structs.

I have a list of meters `[]Meter`

With `Meter`

```
type Meter struct {
    ID          string    `json:"meter_id"`
    ConsoProd   string    `json:"conso_prod"`
    OperationID string    `json:"op_id"`
    Measures    []Measure `json :"measures"`
}
```

The 3 first field will always be here, but Measure has several variants, depending the step in the process.

Here is the general `Measure` struct:

```
// Measure is a measure from a Meter
    type Measure struct {
        IndexName     string    `json:"index_name"`
        IndexValue    int       `json:"index_value"`
        Timestamp     time.Time `json:"timestamp"`
        Delta         float64   `json:"delta"`
        Redistributed float64   `json:"redistributed,omitempty"` // We don t need the redistributed field in Raw Measure
    }
```

First, we get the 'raw value'

```
type RawMeasure struct {
    IndexName     string    `json:"index_name"`
    IndexValue    int       `json:"index_value"`
    Timestamp     time.Time `json:"timestamp"`
    Delta         float64   `json:"delta"`
}
```

Then we will calculate the redistributed, and store it into the `redistributed` field

The measure will never have a redistributed.

Also, I have 2 data sources. If Data comes from source2, it will never have IndexName / IndexValue

```
type RawMeasureFromSource2 struct {
    Timestamp     time.Time `json:"timestamp"`
    Delta         float64   `json:"delta"`
}
```

Here we can see I could create several structs: (RawMeasure, RawMeasureFromSource2, Measure) and then I should create other 3 Meters vars.

As I will manage a lot of data, I need to be careful optimizing memory, but it seems it will complicate my code a lot.

Is there a way to get both a simple code, and optimized memory usage?

Comment: Why so concerned with memory utilization?

Comment: Could you please define *a lot of data*? I'd go for simplicity if the bandwidth is not critically high.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs For 1 meter, I have a measure each 10 minutes ( timestep may vary ). Right now, I have 30 meters, not that much, but it can scale quite quick with big clients

Comment: "I need to be careful optimizing memory" - do you though? Where's your memory benchmarks? Your profiler data? Do you have evidence that you have a memory consumption problem or are you trying to solve a problem you may not actually have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comments, 1 measure every 10 minutes is definitely not a lot.
I'd go for simplicity:

```
type Measure struct {
    IndexName     *string    `json:"index_name,omitempty"`
    IndexValue    *int       `json:"index_value,omitempty"`
    Timestamp      time.Time `json:"timestamp"`
    Delta          float64   `json:"delta"`
    Redistributed *float64   `json:"redistributed,omitempty"`
}
```

Pros:

- Same struct, easy to work with

Cons:

- Few bytes lost on every struct instance

Comment: Using pointers is not handy because we have to test for nil. Why not keep the defaults if the field is undefined ? Omitempty will do the job to not output default values.

Comment: @Andrejs Can you tell me why are you using pointers for optional fields ?

Comment: By using pointer you know if the field is created or not. By not using pointer you can face some corner cases which you need to think of - what should you do if `IndexValue` is set to 0, and this index value is valid, but it's not being served in JSON output due to `omitempty`? You will not face this problem by using pointers, since the default value of this field will be `nil`.

Comment: I see! Thanks for the tip!